# What makes negative number in lubridate?

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

```
(today() %--% ymd("2000-01-01")) %/% years(1)
# -18
(ymd("2000-01-01") %--% today()) %/% years(1)
# 18
```

I think that 2018 - 2000 = 18, not -18

I wonder if I don't completely understand `%--%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has to use `library(lubridate)` to get this infix function in their environment.

So If you go to the documentation of ?`%--%` , it says:

> interval() creates an Interval object with the specified start and end
>   dates. If the start date occurs before the end date, the interval will
>   be positive. Otherwise, it will be negative.

```
interval(today(), ymd("2000-01-01"))/years(1) 
#start date occurs after the end date, this should be negative
```

Printing `interval(today(), ymd("2000-01-01"))` will only show the interval range not the sign, if you use as.numeric or use years(1) division, it will show the sign, hence this happens:

```
> interval(today(), ymd("2000-01-01"))/years(1)
[1] -18.57377
```

The similar behavior happens with the infix function `%--%` as per the documentation:

> %--% Creates an interval that covers the range spanned by two dates.

it works similar to your interval function as it calls interval function. You can check this by printing `` body(`%--%`) `` , Now if you provide first argument in the infix function start date which occurs before the end date the given output is positive else negative.

Remember the function says start and end date which means start should be smaller and end should be a larger date value to get a positive result. In your case today() is end value coming before the start date hence its negative.

I hope this clarifies your doubt.